# Android Spinner arrow closer?

Tags: android, xml, spinner

Can I move the arrow somewhat closer to the text, in a easy way? Don't really understand the purpose of this as default when its transparent.

[image]

```
 <Spinner
  android:id="@+id/spinner_months"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: There's space between "All" and the arrow because there must be an item in Spinner with longer width. One way to make it look better is by putting a separator between two Spinners.

Answer (score 3):

I have answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42596698/1260126

This can be achieved by creating a custom layout for the selected spinner item custom_spinner_item.xml. I have added a TextView which displays the currently selected spinner item. The arrow icon is added in an ImageView. You can use any icon. The arrow icon moves depending on the length of the text. In fact you can completely modify the look of your spinner in this layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinner_item_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_arrow_down"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Create a custom spinner adapter and inflate the above view. Also set the text of your selected spinner item from your list by overriding the default getView() method.

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<String> spinnerItems;

    public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context applicationContext, int resource, List<String> spinnerItems) {
        super(applicationContext, resource, spinnerItems);
        this.spinnerItems = spinnerItems;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_item, null);
        TextView type = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_item_text);
        type.setText(spinnerItems.get(i));
        return view;
    }
}
```

Then instantiate the CustomSpinnerAdapter class and set it as your spinner's adapter. spinnerList is the list of items to be shown in the spinner.

```
CustomSpinnerAdapter customSpinnerAdapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerList);
spinner.setAdapter(customSpinnerAdapter);
```

Comment: The `TextView` id in the `xml` does not match the one in the java class. fwiw, this method showed the `LinearLayout` over the original `Spinner` background (per style spec); fixed this issue by setting `android:background="@null"` Thanks

Comment: Awesome solution!